# $brand-primary in laravel bootstrap variables not global

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, sass

I have laravel v5.4. In my _variables.scss i defined the primary color:

```
$brand-primary: red;
```

This changes everything bootstrap related to red which is nice. But then i have also added my own scss in app.scss:

```
@import "variables";
@import "custom/custom";
```

And in custom i have the following row:

```
color: $brand-primary;
```

... but for some reason this turns the color to original bootstrap brand primary, not my red. How can i get my red color everywhere i use $brand-primary?

Comment: Have you checked in inspect element? There could be an imported override? Reset the cache - try in a different browser?

Comment: Or just added !important to your tag:

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap variable is overriding your variable definition.
Make sure you are importing your file AFTER importing bootstrap variables' file.

Also, are you importing your '_variables.scss' file?

Comment: Yep, import order is: import "variables"; import "custom/custom";